# woocommerce. как отправлять данные при регистрации на внешний сервер, при этом чтобы клиент не сохранялся в wp?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

при регистрации клиента в магазине нужно отправлять введенные данные на внешний сервер, при этом чтобы в БД wp данные не сохранялись, соответственно при входе уже имеющегося пользователя тоже будет отправляться запрос и на внешнем сервере выполнятся проверка, то есть в итоге данные о пользователях, в будущем и о заказах будут хранится на стороннем сервере и получатся от туда
как это сделать не понимаю, куда копать?
буду благодарен за любую информацию

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать реализовать как любое приложение на `React`. На другом сервере разворачиваем магазин и пишем нужную апишку. На нужном домене потом выводим нужные страницы с товарами и формами регистрации. Получается фронт в одном месте, а бэк в другом.

Много работы с апишкой будет, много работы с `javascript`.

Или делать интернет магазин как обычно и потом при помощи апи работать с другим сервером.

Ниже пример обращения к методу 1С через АПИ

```
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', 0);

$client = new SoapClient("http://111.111.111.111/trade2/ws?wsdl", 
    array(
        'login'         => "LOGIN", //логин пользователя к базе 1С
        'password'      => "PASSWORD", //пароль пользователя к базе 1С
        'soap_version'  => SOAP_1_2, //версия SOAP
        'cache_wsdl'    => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'trace'         => true,
        'features'      => SOAP_USE_XSI_ARRAY_TYPE
    )
);

//Заполним массив передаваемых параметров
$params = [
    'user_name'     => $user_name,
    'user_login'    => $user_login,
    'user_pass'     => $user_pass,
];
//Выполняем операцию

$result = $client->nameFunction1C($params); // nameFunction1C - это метод веб-сервиса 1С, который описан в конфигурации 1C.
$Bonus = $result->return; // тут ответ от 1С - Пользователь зарегистрирован
```

От специалистов 1С вам нужно будет название метода и какие данные он принимает. И лучше передавать в таком же порядке как у них в АПИ записаны.

Comment: к сожалению так невозможно, бэк уже есть и это 1С, там нужно хранить данные магазина

Comment: тогда пусть специалисты 1С пишут апишку которая будет принимать нужные данные. Для начала данные зарегистрированных пользователей. Они это умеют. А вам останется собрать данные из формы и отправить им. Такой же апишкой будет идти проверка при авторизации.